# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in cakephp-2.2.0 project with php7

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in cakephp-2.2.0 project with php7

Project was written in php-5, now the system has php-7.

Full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php:2298 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(1050): DboSource->fields(Object(Post), 'Post', 'COUNT(*) AS `co...') #1 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2631): DboSource->read(Object(Post), Array) #2 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php(185): Model->find('count', Array) #3 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(1082): PaginatorComponent->paginate(Object(Post), Array, Array) #4 /var/www/html/allblog/app/Controller/AppController.php(66): Controller->paginate('Post') #5 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Controller/CakeErrorController.php(74): AppController->beforeRender() #6 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(246): CakeErrorController->beforeRender(Object(CakeEvent)) #7 /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(922): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent)) #8 /var/ in /var/www/html/allblog/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 2298
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My suggestion would be to upgrade CakePHP

Comment: @user2182349 Upgrade to what? cakephp v2 -> v3  seems very non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CakeText` istead of.

> Is recommended as it offers compatibility with PHP7 and HHVM.

See: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html